# Using MaterializeCSS with Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, materialize

I'm following the tutorial here http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial/4

and I added bootstrap as per the instructions and it all works according to plan

there's a config that I have to add to the vendor part of the `aurelia.json` file

```
"dependencies": [
  ...
  "jquery",
  {
    "name": "bootstrap",
    "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
    "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
    "deps": ["jquery"],
    "exports": "$",
    "resources": [
      "css/bootstrap.css"
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

but I like materialize-css and I figure I could just install materialize-css via npm and then change the bootstrap bit of the config to this

```
      {
        "name": "materialize-css",
        "path": "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist",
        "main": "js/materialize",
        "deps": ["jquery"],
        "exports": "$",
        "resources": [
          "css/materialize.css"
        ]
      }
```

when I use this in app.html

```
<require from="materialize-css/css/materialize.css"></require>
```

the app blows up with a `Unhandled rejection Error: Failed loading required CSS file: materialize-css/css/materialize.css`

I can't work out why this is the case. To me it seems like I did a like for like swap of css frameworks

Comment: can you confirm that this is installed and its not just 404ing?

Comment: Yes materialize-css is in the node_modules directory.

Comment: Materialize has its css in the dist or bin folder. Either one should work.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with it.
Check the instructions http://aurelia-ui-toolkits.github.io/demo-materialize/#/installation in case missed a step